# how to make the td width fixed?

Tags: html, css, html-table, column-width

I want to make the column's width is as width as it's content, but now it looks like this:

[image]

the relative code is shown as followed:

[image]

I have tried so many ways to fix this, but neither worked, what's the problem, how can I fix this?

---

the console show like this:

[image]

Comment: can you add Js Fiddle...So I an help you

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle using `colgroup` https://jsfiddle.net/j6vdk8c0/

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="100px">
    <col width="200px">
    <col width="300px">
    <col width="400px">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Specify your width you want on `col`. Make your `col` width depends on your content.

Comment: When i set it as 50px, it became longer,  still full of the screen

Comment: Do you want the width of the table depends on the content? or the width of the column?

Comment: both are ok,  because both would be defined width

Comment: sorry again, it didn't work . Dose it have any boostrap way to fix this!

Comment: What exactly you want to happen?

Comment: I want the tag <table class="table"> exactly. And I want every width of the column could be fixed instead of being stretched while the sum of the width could not reach 100% width. For example, if the total <th> could only  have 50% of the screen width, then a half side of the screen should be blank, instead of doubling the width of the column automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `display:table` instead of tables

Example:

```css
.table {
   display: table;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
 
.table .table-row {
   display: table-row;
}
 
.table .table-cell {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: left;
   vertical-align: top;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
 <div class="table-row">
  <div class="table-cell">test</div>
  <div class="table-cell">test1123</div>
 </div>
 <div class="table-row">
  <div class="table-cell">test</div>
  <div class="table-cell">test123</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, it didn't work.It's much longer than it's content (test123)

Comment: yeah because "test1123" is longer and the colum has to fit at least the content of "test1123" but in your example the buttons are all the same size so it should work for you

Answer (score -1):

@wuxue you can directly use inline css style="width:;" or create a class in css and apply it.